# Subquery with multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, multiple-columns

I have SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.inn, 
                t1.idx, 
                (SELECT TOP 1 adr 
                 FROM   t2 
                 WHERE  t2.idx = t1.idx 
                        AND t2.inn = t1.inn) ADR, 
                (SELECT TOP 1 name 
                 FROM   t2 
                 WHERE  t2.idx = t1.idx 
                        AND t2.inn = t1.inn) NAME 
FROM   t1
```

Is it possible to make one subquery instead two? (i.e. select TOP 1 ADR and NAME simultaneously). Server: MS SQL 2008-2012.

Comment: You use `TOP` without `ORDER BY`. What result do you expect?

Comment: I want to get unique combinations of INN and IDX with some ADR and NAME. Each couple of INN-IDX corresponds number of ADR-NAME. I want get any one of them (no matter what exactly). For ex. in table exist 3 rows: INN = 111, IDX=101, ADR=A1, NAME = N1; INN = 111, IDX=101, ADR = B1, NAME = N1; INN = 222, IDX=202, ADR=A2, NAME = N2; I'd like to get result with two rows: INN=111, IDX=101 and INN=222, IDX=202, with any ADR (i.e. does not matter A1 or B1 for first row)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `cross apply`:

```
select distinct t1.INN, t1.IDX, t2.adr, t2.name
from t1 cross apply
     (select top 1 adr, name
      from t2
      where t2.idx = t1.idx and t2.inn = t1.inn
     ) t2;
```

However, you are selecting one row without an order by.  If there is only one row that matches, then you can do this with a regular join.

Comment: There is not only one row matches but i don't use order by because it is does'nt matter what exactly ADR and NAME will be selected. I just need any one ADR/NAME for each distinct INN/IDX